# Pivot Table Omitting Rows that Have Null values

Tags: mysql, pivot-table, group-concat

I am solving a problem very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table) only in my case, I am not summing any values.

I have been able to write a select that works using solution from [this page](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78)

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(colID = 1, value, NULL)) AS 'First Name',
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(colID = 2, value, NULL)) AS 'Last Name',
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(colID = 3, value, NULL)) AS 'Job Title'
FROM tbl
GROUP BY id;
```

However, I want to omit rows that have the `value` to be null

Comment: So you want to omit the row from the *result* if *any* of the source rows for the same id has `value IS NULL`? Please clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to drop the result row if *any* of the source rows has `value IS NULL`.
You should be able to achieve that with [**bit_and()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_bit-and) in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT id
     , max(CASE WHEN colID = 1 THEN value END) AS fn
     , max(CASE WHEN colID = 2 THEN value END) AS ln
     , max(CASE WHEN colID = 3 THEN value END) AS jt
FROM   tbl 
GROUP  BY id
HAVING bit_and(value IS NOT NULL);
```

Alternative:

```
...
HAVING count(*) = count(value);
```

I didn't spell out `ELSE NULL` in the CASE statements because ([per documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case)):

> If there was no matching result value, the result after `ELSE` is returned, or `NULL` if there is no `ELSE` part.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this constraint to the where statement of your query, like this:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(colID = 1, value, NULL)) AS 'First Name',
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(colID = 2, value, NULL)) AS 'Last Name',
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(colID = 3, value, NULL)) AS 'Job Title'
FROM tbl
WHERE value IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY id;
```

**EDIT**

After some tests I could make a solution to work, but it seems interesting why `value is not null` won't work.

Solution link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7a445/3

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  max(case when colID = 1 then value else '' end) AS fn,
  max(case when colID = 2 then value else '' end) AS ln,
  max(case when colID = 3 then value else '' end) AS jt
FROM tbl 
where not exists (select * from tbl b where tbl.id=b.id and value is null)
group by id
```

Comment: sorry, for the confusion I caused. `value` is the column I'm trying to place the constraint on

Comment: Then change the where statement to `value IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Doesn't work (see [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f5692/2/0)) I want to last row in the query to be omitted.

Comment: I'm testing your query and I find it very odd that it isn't working. it seems that mysql group function is ignoring the `not null` constraint (where clause). And in order to check whether it is a default behavior or not I tested on the other databases and only oracle worked as it should (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8870c/1). made a few changes on the query in my tests but it is the same principle. So we have to ask to the database experts in a new question why is this happening.

Comment: @GordonLinoff could you help us here about this?

Comment: I find a solution but it seems not too obvious. I will make a question about this discussion. I will edit the answer with the final query and the sql fiddle.

Comment: @iroegbu if you, like me, is curious enough to understand why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518305/mysql-postgre-oracle-and-sqlserver-ignoring-is-not-null-filter :)

Comment: I tried all kinds of funny things in `WHERE` clause... see, accepted answer, pretty clean.

Comment: @iroegbu Its a nice answer indeed! It was him that clarify the problem. It is absurdly simple. I was thinking about filter the value, but it was the ID that it was beeing grouped that matter. So  you have three registries with id 3 and one of then with null value, the where clause was filtering it but when you pivot the table you still have two of then. :)